# django navbar template - tags

Tags: django, django-templates, django-context

I have created 2 navbars one for blog and one for the main app. I use include tag to introduce navbar into templates. "extends base.html" is also used however, navbar is not included in the base file and as  mentioned above is introduced as include tag.

In the main app which is supposed to render same navbar(contents) for all pages of the app is not doing so, and I only receive the desired result on the homepage.

The context variables used on the navbar are from the homepage view function and when homepage page is rendered it works perfectly however when I open any internal pages of the same app the navbar does not show any of the content.

I presume navbar would try and load context variables of the view function of the active(currently opened) html page only and so homepage context variables do not work on any other page, even though navbar is a separate html file.

If this is correct I wanted to know how to get around it as all the pages on the main app should show the same navbar values.

```
home.html - This is how base and navbar are introduced in the template. 
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block title %}Title{% endblock title %}
{% block navbar %}{% include 'navbar.html' %}{% endblock navbar%}
```

Similarly rest of the pages introduce both base and navbar.

All context variables used in navbar {% for country in countries %} for example are from view function for the home page.

When I use the same navbar for say "about us" page the navbar does not show the required information.

Does that help?

Comment: Can you show us some code to make your problem more understandable?

Comment: @MaximeLorant I have the code but not too much to avoid further confusion. Hope this helps. Let me know if you need more information.

Comment: please specify where you want to display which navbar.

Comment: I would want my navbar to be dynamic and so I am using context variables.  But the context variables only load when I use it on home page and do not work when used on any other html page. This is because I am only using context variable of the home page view function. Does that help?

Answer (score 0):

simple way you can do

```
in base.html

    {% block content %}
    {% endblock %}

    in navbar2.html file
    all html code


in navbar2.html file
        all html code



    other1.html file
    {% extends 'base.html'%}

    {% blck content %}
    {% include 'navbar1.html' %}


    All html code here
    {% endblock %}

other2.html file
        {% extends 'base.html'%}
        {% blck content %}

        {% include 'navbar1.html' %}

        All html code here
        {% endblock %}
```

if you want send the context variables to all files then create view which will render to base.html and pass that context variables to base.html. As base.html is extended in each templates, so you will get access for that context variables in all templates

Comment: Base is a simple html file does not use context variables whereas navbar does. I understand I can make it simpler by adding the  navbar into base file. The reason why I don't do it is because I have different navbar to use for my blog app and a different one on my main app. However, the is not my  problem I want to be able to use context variables from one view function on all the html pages. Even if I were to add navbar to base I would still need to use context variables.

Comment: You should consider cleaning up your answer... it's a bit of a mess and some of the file names are wrong